# Ruby libraries or formats for cooking recipes

Tags: ruby, format, recipe

I'm starting to implement a website for a client that needs to save and export cooking recipes. There needs to be a CRUD edit portion and export to templated PDF.

I've been trying to research existing formats (file-based or database) to save recipes. I don't want to just start designing a schema, as I've got a feeling it'll not be trivial. Additionally, I'd like to base the app on the most commonly used format, so import/export will be easier.

This page: http://microformats.org/wiki/recipe-formats lists some file formats for recipes, but none strike me as "the definite" format.

So the question is twofold:

Is there a recipe file format that is generally accepted as the "industry standard" ?

and

Are there any libraries (preferably in Ruby) for managing recipes ? Tools like chef and capistrano make it impossible to google this...